# ElasticSearch Clustering- Creating Index creates unassigned shards

Tags: elasticsearch, status, clustered-index

Hello Guys while creating index in elasticsearch cluster, All my replication shards are in UNASSIGNED state due to which i am not able to reindex and the cluster goes to red status.
Can you guys help this is I have spend nights to solve this.

Update -- 
Number of Nodes are 2.

```
"cluster_name": "cluster-name",
   "status": "red",
   "timed_out": false,
   "number_of_nodes": 2,
   "number_of_data_nodes": 2,
   "active_primary_shards": 2,
   "active_shards": 2,
   "relocating_shards": 0,
   "initializing_shards": 3,
   "unassigned_shards": 5,
   "delayed_unassigned_shards": 0,
   "number_of_pending_tasks": 0,
   "number_of_in_flight_fetch": 0,
   "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis": 0,
   "active_shards_percent_as_number": 20
```

I am creating just 8 shards and 1 replication shards.
While doing this all my replication shards goes to unassigned state and all my shards of non-master node goes to initializing state.

Also whenever i delete this index my cluster comes to green state.

**UPDATE**

**LOGS**

```
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpChunkAggregator.messageReceived(HttpChunkAggregator.java:194)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.messageReceived(HttpContentDecoder.java:135)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:452)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:536)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:435)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:75)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2016-02-19 16:23:06,846][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [tyroo-es-1] [abc] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [4]/[1], mappings []
[2016-02-19 16:23:16,095][INFO ][rest.suppressed          ] /products_staging/products_staging/_search Params: {size=10, index=products_staging, from=0, type=products_staging}
[products_staging] IndexNotFoundException[no such index]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.IndexNameExpressionResolver$WildcardExpressionResolver.resolve(IndexNameExpressionResolver.java:586)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.IndexNameExpressionResolver.concreteIndices(IndexNameExpressionResolver.java:133)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.IndexNameExpressionResolver.concreteIndices(IndexNameExpressionResolver.java:113)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.<init>(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:121)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction$AsyncAction.<init>(TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.java:73)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction$AsyncAction.<init>(TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.java:67)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.doExecute(TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.java:64)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.doExecute(TransportSearchQueryThenFetchAction.java:53)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:70)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.TransportSearchAction.doExecute(TransportSearchAction.java:99)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.TransportSearchAction.doExecute(TransportSearchAction.java:44)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:70)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.doExecute(NodeClient.java:58)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:351)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.FilterClient.doExecute(FilterClient.java:52)
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.BaseRestHandler$HeadersAndContextCopyClient.doExecute(BaseRestHandler.java:83)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:351)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.search(AbstractClient.java:574)
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.action.search.RestSearchAction.handleRequest(RestSearchAction.java:84)
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.BaseRestHandler.handleRequest(BaseRestHandler.java:54)
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.executeHandler(RestController.java:207)
    at org.elasticsearch.rest.RestController.dispatchRequest(RestController.java:166)
    at org.elasticsearch.http.HttpServer.internalDispatchRequest(HttpServer.java:128)
    at org.elasticsearch.http.HttpServer$Dispatcher.dispatchRequest(HttpServer.java:86)
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty.NettyHttpServerTransport.dispatchRequest(NettyHttpServerTransport.java:363)
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty.HttpRequestHandler.messageReceived(HttpRequestHandler.java:63)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.messageReceived(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:60)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:88)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpChunkAggregator.messageReceived(HttpChunkAggregator.java:194)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.messageReceived(HttpContentDecoder.java:135)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:452)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:536)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:435)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:75)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Please, post the content of the log file from the master node.

Comment: There are no such logs while creating an index.

Comment: Can you, please, provide the logs? There can be other clues in there.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have sufficient disk storage to store primary shards, your cluster state will turn into red. If your configured data node disk goes beyond 90% your cluster turns into yellow. So please check data node's configured disk storage.

Comment: thanks for replying. I had around 150Gb of space free. 
I didnt understand the problem by a clean and new setup of elasticsearch worked for me